# What is a shortened word that is used as an insult called?

Tags: single-word-requests

In this example someone calling a person who likes or practices **traditional architecture** a **Trad**

I think along the same lines as calling a **communist** a **commie**

Comment: I would call it a derogatory (or pejorative) diminutive and not look for a dedicated term that no one has heard of. Come to think of it, "diminutive" is obscure enough to begin with.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Pejorative is good.

Comment: Changed tags. You're not asking about pejorative language; you're asking for a word to identify pejorative language.

Comment: A shortened word for any purpose is an abbreviated form. If you change it in any other way and it gains common acceptance, it is a form of colloquialism. It could be a pejorative as well, but that has nothing to do with shortening the word.

Answer (score -2):

There can be various adjectives, nouns and verbs which can be used to describe or name an insulting shortened word.

Depending on the word and its usage, it could be:

- [racist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/racist) or [racism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/racism)
- antisemitist, [antisemitic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anti-semitic) or antisemitism
- [hate speech](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hate_speech)...

The words are [derogatory](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/derogatory) in nature.

[Slang](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slang) as an *informal* verb can be used to attack someone using abusive language.

> he watched ideological groups slanging one another

There is also [colloquial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colloquial) or [colloquialism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colloquialism)

These words can also be described as [hate words](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hate%20word).

Answer (score -2):

In English, there are many different endings and ways of abbreviating a word in order to give it negative meaning or to have control over the subject which it is describing.  In the example of "traditional" being abbreviated to "trad," there is nothing inherently wrong with being a traditionalist, however in shortening it to "trad" the speaker has some control over the meaning of the word.  Adding an adverb or adjective would emphasize that; "He's *just* a trad," or "My prof's a *real* trad."  Notice in the example, I shortened "professor" to "prof."  This is also done with "doctor" which can be said "doc."  "Coppers" (an earlier name for policeman) was shortened to "cop."  Now, people use the word "cop" and no one would consider it negative.  In the example of "communist," "commie" is not positive and was specifically shortened in order to be condescending.

I would call these [abbreviations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abbreviation), and then depending on their use say they were [pejoratives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pejorative).  So I would call "commie" a pejorative, and "trad" an abbreviation.  Some words are abbreviated *and* pejorative, so I would say they were pejorative abbreviations.  Words such as "[Tranny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tranny)," "Homo," or "Psycho," I would call pejorative abbreviations.